# Is it possible to retrieve the MS / Latency from a "GET" request? (Javascript / Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, latency

I am at the moment making some getjson requests with jquery.

They are get requests: **"GET http://localhost/MySite/JSON"**

Now you can watch the requests fire in firebug. Then they return a **"200 OK 250ms"**.
I would like to be able to display something similar on my page itself. So the user can see the latency for themselves.
[Firebug Image http://testnscale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/firebug.png](http://testnscale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/firebug.png)
*Image found via google from http://testnscale.com*

**Is it possible to retrieve the MS / Latency from a "GET" request?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try it and check if those values you're measuring are the same or close to it.

Like

```
var startTime;
$.ajax
({
    // .. url, type, dataType, etc
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
        startTime = +new Date();
    },
    complete: function(xhr, state)
    {
        var latency = (+new Date()) - startTime;
    }
});
```

I'm actually curious about that, so let us know your results.
what you are getting is the difference in miliseconds.

Comment: there is a typo in the beforeSend function . Instead of time , the variable should be startTime :)

Comment: It works well. Will always be at least within 200ms in my testing 90% of the time within 40ms. Does what I'll need it to do so thankyou muchly :)

Comment: @Ozaki: ah nice. I thought there is maybe more overhead by doing it manually.