# Latency measurement of every request

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, latency

Is there any way by which latency details can be extracted from browser using JavaScript?

[image: example picture]

For example: when we enter url and press enter, after some time we got response back. So the difference between pressing enter and getting response.

I just wanted to extract first bar time in picture. [The technique in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155960/is-it-possible-to-retreive-the-ms-latency-from-a-get-request-javascript) measures latency of only AJAX calls. Is it possible or not?

Please avoid `window.onload`, by this we can only measure load time latency.

Comment: You need to check if your browser vendor exposes such an API. JavaScript doesn't specify if the browser should do that. [Chrome has a page dedicated to its API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) which can tell you such info. For other browsers that you might use, you need to consult their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the code of the page you're trying to measure the requests from, you could use the navigation timing API (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing) and a  [useful blog post](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/introduction-navigation-timing-api/)), to determine the time to first byte, which sounds like the latency you're after. You can also measure other factors, some that might affect overall latency, like DNS lookup, too.